# Merge rows in the same data.frame [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data.frame with the specific format:

```
df <- structure(list(Left.align = c("A", "B", "C", "F"), Right.align = c("B", 
"A", "D", "E"), Center.align = c(2, 2, 3, 6)), .Names = c("Left.align", 
"Right.align", "Center.align"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df
  Left.align Right.align Center.align
1          A           B            2
2          B           A            2
3          C           D            3
4          F           E            6
```

I would to remove B A 2, because the result is the same that A B 2. How will I do this in R?

thanks!

Comment: Just do `df1[!duplicated(t(apply(df1, 1, sort))),]`

Answer (score 1):

We can `sort` by row and then use `duplicated` to get a logical index to subset the rows of dataset

```
df1[!duplicated(t(apply(df1, 1, sort))),]
```

Comment: If I have a table with the same characters in different columns, for example: 1          A           A            2  How Could I remove this rows? thanks

Comment: @LeandroNascimentoLemos  Do you want to remove those columns?